# Android login Error

Tags: android, database, authentication

I am making a login page. In the following code, `userEntered` and `pswdEntered` are `EditText` collecting user input. I pass `userEntered` as a parameter in method `getSingleEntry` in my database. I want this method to check the username in the database and return the corresponding password back. How will the method `getSingleEntry` look?

```
        boolean diditwork = true;
        try {
        String userEntered= user.getText().toString();
        String pswdEntered = pswd.getText().toString();
    String storedPassword=LoginDB.getSingleEntry(userEntered);

        Log.d("blahhhhhhhhh", storedPassword);

         if(pswdEntered.equals(storedPassword))
         {

                Dialog id=new Dialog(Login.this);
                id.setTitle("LOGIN");
                TextView tyv=new TextView(Login.this);
                tyv.setText("Registration Successful!");
                id.setContentView(tyv);

         }
         else
         {

                Dialog id=new Dialog(Login.this);
                id.setTitle("LOGIN");
                TextView tyv=new TextView(Login.this);
                tyv.setText("Incorrect username or password!");
                id.setContentView(tyv);
                id.show();

         }

        }   /*  catch(SQLException ee)
        {
            diditwork=false;
            String error=ee.toString();
            Dialog id=new Dialog(Login.this);
            id.setTitle("SQLSQLSQLSQL");
            TextView tyv=new TextView(Login.this);
            tyv.setText(error);
            id.setContentView(tyv);
            id.show();
        }*/
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            diditwork=false;
            String error=e.toString();
            Dialog id=new Dialog(Login.this);
            id.setTitle("LOGIN");
            TextView tyv=new TextView(Login.this);
            tyv.setText("Retype password"+error );
            id.setContentView(tyv);
            id.show();
        }
```

These are the database definitions.

```
                   public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
                   public static final String KEY_NAME= "name";
                   public static final String KEY_USERNAME="username";
                   public static final String KEY_PASSWORD="password";
               public static final String KEY_MOBILE= "mobile";
               public static final String KEY_EMAIL= "email";

                   private static final String DATABASE_NAME="LoginDB";
                   private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="DoctorTable";
                   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=2;
```

Comment: post your `getSingleEntry()`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getSingleEntry(String userName)
{
    Log.d("db", userName);
    Cursor c;
    String[] columns= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_USERNAME,KEY_PASSWORD,KEY_MOBILE,KEY_EMAIL};
//  String[] columns= new String[]{KEY_PASSWORD};

     c = db.rawQuery("SELECT password FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE username=?", new String[]{userName});
//   c=db.query("LoginDB", columns,KEY_USERNAME + "=" + userName ,null, null, null, null);
  // c = db.rawQuery("SELECT password FROM " + DATABASE_NAME + " WHERE username ='"+userName+"'", null);    
  // c= db.rawQuery("SELECT "+ KEY_PASSWORD + "FROM" + DATABASE_NAME + "WHERE" + KEY_USERNAME + "= ?", new String[] {userName});
  // c= db.rawQuery("SELECT password FROM 'LoginDB' WHERE username ="+userName, null);


     if(c!=null)
     {
     c.moveToFirst();
     String password= c.getString(3);
     Log.d("ruuuu",password);
     c.close();
     return password;     
    }
     return null;


}
```